# function is not defined error in react-scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
 import * as Scroll from 'react-scroll';  
 componentDidMount() {    
     Scroll.Events.scrollEvent.register('end', () => {
     this.checkScrollForMobile();
 });

 checkScrollForMobile(){}
```

Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: checkScrollForMobile is not defined" error though I've defined it below. Please help.

Comment: A guess: have you tried moving `checkScrollForMobile` function to _before_ `componentDidMount`?

Comment: did'nt work. looks like `this` object is not recognised inside the callback function.

Comment: this. checkScrollForMobile = this. checkScrollForMobile.bind(this);
this was the solution :) had to bind 'this' object